# What is the right way to create a Firestore Timestamp object in a rules test data set?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing tests for Firestore rules, and I want to test rules limiting when actions are performed (before/after a timestamp stored on the document).

The rules will, of course, be dealing with [rules.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.timestamp) and not JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects. Thus, I want to create `Timestamp` objects in my test data.

If, however, I import `@google-cloud/firestore` to get the `Timestamp` data type, I get a horrible error when I try to compile the test:

```
functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentData, UpdateData, Firestore, GeoPoint, Transaction, WriteBatch, WriteResult, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot, OrderByDirection, WhereFilterOp, Query, QuerySnapshot, DocumentChangeType, CollectionReference, FieldValue, FieldPath, Timestamp, v1beta1, v1, OK, CANCELLED, UNKNOWN, INVALID_ARGUMENT, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, NOT_FOUND, ALREADY_EXISTS, PERMISSION_DENIED, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, FAILED_PRECONDITION, ABORTED, OUT_OF_RANGE, UNIMPLEMENTED, INTERNAL, UNAVAILABLE, DATA_LOSS, UNAUTHENTICATED, FirebaseFirestore

23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
   ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1
    23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
       ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentData, UpdateData, Firestore, GeoPoint, Transaction, WriteBatch, WriteResult, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot, OrderByDirection, WhereFilterOp, Query, QuerySnapshot, DocumentChangeType, CollectionReference, FieldValue, FieldPath, Timestamp, v1beta1, v1, OK, CANCELLED, UNKNOWN, INVALID_ARGUMENT, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, NOT_FOUND, ALREADY_EXISTS, PERMISSION_DENIED, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, FAILED_PRECONDITION, ABORTED, OUT_OF_RANGE, UNIMPLEMENTED, INTERNAL, UNAVAILABLE, DATA_LOSS, UNAUTHENTICATED, FirebaseFirestore

23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
   ~~~~~~~

  functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1
    23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
       ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.

node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:147:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.

147     [key: string]: any; // Accept other properties, such as GRPC settings.
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is an entire test file which will demonstrate the problem:

```js
import * as firebase from '@firebase/testing';
import * as fs from "fs";
import {suite, test} from "mocha-typescript";
import * as chai from 'chai';
import {Timestamp} from "@google-cloud/firestore";

const projectId = 'stackoverflow-timestamp';
const coverageUrl = `http://localhost:8080/emulator/v1/projects/${projectId}:ruleCoverage.html`;
const rules = fs.readFileSync('firestore.rules', 'utf8');

const nowMillis = Date.now();
const yesterday = Timestamp.fromMillis(nowMillis - 86400000);
const tomorrow = Timestamp.fromMillis(nowMillis + 86400000);

const test_data = {
    'timesamples/ts1': {
        'createTime': yesterday,
        'closeTime': tomorrow
    }
};

/**
 * Creates a new app with authentication data matching the input.
 *
 * @param {object} auth the object to use for authentication (typically {uid: some-uid})
 * @return {object} the app
 */
function authedApp(auth) {
    return firebase.initializeTestApp({'projectId': projectId, 'auth': auth}).firestore();
}

/*
 * ============
 *  Test Cases
 * ============
 */
before(async () => {
    await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({projectId, rules});
});

beforeEach(async () => {
    // Clear the database between tests
    await firebase.clearFirestoreData({projectId});
    const db = firebase.initializeAdminApp({'projectId': projectId}).firestore();
    // load the test data
    for (const key in test_data) {
        const ref = db.doc(key);
        await ref.set(test_data[key]);
    }
});

after(async () => {
    await Promise.all(firebase.apps().map(app => app.delete()));
    console.log(`View rule coverage information at ${coverageUrl}\n`);
});

@suite
class TimestampRuleChecks {
    @test
    async 'modify when close is in future'() {
        const unauthenticated = authedApp(null);
        const record = unauthenticated.collection('timesamples').doc('ts1');
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(
            record.set({'data': 'modifiedData'}, {merge: true})
                .catch(
                    (reason => {
                            chai.assert.fail("Problem in Firebase: " + reason);
                        }
                    )
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to show a complete, minimal set of code where you see this problem?  Strip it down to the bare minimum, so there can be no ambiguity where the conflict is coming from.

Comment: If you have TS3.8+ trying something like `import type {Timestamp} from "@google-cloud/firestore";` and see if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't actually address the import problem, so it's probably technically not an answer to the question. However, I have found that my tests work (comparing mock data to `request.time`) when I define the mock data with regular `Date` objects.

Comment: Does this really (still) work? `Unsupported operation error. Received: string > timestamp. Expected: string > string, bytes > bytes, int > int, float > float, duration > duration, timestamp > timestamp, constraint > any, any > constraint.`